# How to authenticate google_client using API Keys in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, youtube-api, google-client

Like js I just need apikey to authenticate and can call other api like google_service_youtube

```
function loadClient() {
    gapi.client.setApiKey("xxxxxxxxRc6V7p6WlZsar0elij3wJxxbn8owBNr8");
    return gapi.client.load("https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/youtube/v3/rest")
        .then(function() { console.log("GAPI client loaded for API"); },
            function(err) { console.error("Error loading GAPI client for API", err); });
}

gapi.load("client:auth2", function() {
    gapi.auth2.init({ client_id: "xxxxxxxxx-ib4ithohjejiv213ju49m1tts0bgqtfh.apps.googleusercontent.com" });
    loadClient()
});
```

call api youtube

```
function handleGetView() {
            return gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({ "part": ["statistics"], "id": ['EYGI-rdg9ts']
            }).then(function(response) {
                console.log("Response", response);
            },function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });
        }
```

on laravel there is any code similar to that?

Comment: Laravel uses `.env` files to [store environment variables](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#introduction) such as API keys from a third party provider.

Comment: but on laravel i can't do so can you give me examples okay ?

Comment: Check out Laracasts.

Comment: What is the issue with your current solution?  Do you have an error message?